# UIKit: Why is my indexPath off by one when calling tableView.indexPathForRow(at: to:)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm noticing odd behavior in one of the UITableView methods (tableView.indexPathForRow(at: to:)) which is usually used to get the index path of a row that is interacted with in a UITableView. I've used this many times perfectly fine but on a new project (built with Xcode 14) it's not working and the index is off by one.

I stripped everything down to the most basic elements and created a tag on a checkbox in my TestCell with the tag number set to the indexPath.row value created in cellForRowAt so I know that the cell is in the correct place.

The problem is when the testButton method is called, the indexPath given by tableView.indexPathForRow is off by one. This obviously crashes the app when I hit the button on the first cell, if I hit the button on the second cell the first row's button toggles on.

I've already looked at all the other Stack Overflow questions regarding this and none were able to solve this issue. I'm not interested in a work-around that's easy enough, I'm trying to identify if this is indeed a bug on Apple's end or a mistake in my code that I've overlooked. None of my other apps using this function built with earlier versions of Xcode have this issue.

```
import UIKit

class TestListViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureTableView()
    }
}

extension TestListViewController {

    private func configureTableView() {
        tableView.register(TestCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TestCell")
    }

    @objc func testButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)) else {
            return
        }
        print("Tag: \(sender.tag)") //This comes up as expected
        print("IndexPath: \(indexPath)")    //This does not, index is off by one! 
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell", for: indexPath) as! TestCell
    
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.checkbox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testButton(_ :)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.checkbox.tag = indexPath.row
   
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably using the wrong point or translating into the wrong view. It would be much better, and safer to  have the button tap handler in your cell and have it pass itself to a closure or delegate method.  Then you can use `indexPath(for:)` to get the index path for the cell.

Comment: Does `sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)` look correct to you?

Comment: @Sweeper yes. It's getting the first point of the sender which is the UIButton.

Comment: @Paulw11 Nope it's the correct point and the correct view. The point is just the coordinates of the sender which is the UIButton on the cell.

Comment: Did you tried with center point of button instead , just in case some rounding with y=0 may cause the wrong cell to be computed.

Comment: @PtitXav You nailed it, it's some kind of weird rounding error or something with using CGPoint.zero. It's strange because this code is probably in 20 something apps of mine and I never had an issue but for some reason on this new app it's causing an issue. 

Thanks so much!

Comment: @SN81 the correct approach would be to add an indexPath property to your custom cell and set it before returning it in your table view cellForRowAt method

Comment: We have a solution marking system here, so [solved] devices in the title are not necessary. Could you write a self-answer? You can click the tick/check symbol to mark it as solved if you wish.

Comment: @LeoDabus While that approach may work in this case, it is not a solution that I would recommend generally. It is similar to using the `tag`; it breaks if any table re-ordering or cell insertion/deletion is possible.

Comment: Well you can get the visible cells and update them if needed.